# How to calculate monthly average of multiple columns in dataframe based on Date column with missind data in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, average, multiple-columns

I have large number of columns in my dataframe over 4000. One column is of Date and rest are Companies (Column Names). I have daily obervations for 14 years (as rows) making it be 164 months .I want to calculate mothly averages based on the Date column and most important of all the average should only be calculated when there are atleast 15 observations for each column(company) otherwise should return NA.

```
df<- Spread
Date             A             B    C
2000-01-04  0.062893082 0.030769231 NA
2000-01-05  0.062893082 0.015503876 NA
2000-01-06  0.062893082 NA          NA
2000-01-07  0.062893082 NA          NA
2000-01-10  0.062893082 NA          NA
2000-01-11  0.062893082 NA          NA
2000-01-12  0.062893082 NA          NA
2000-01-13  0.062893082 NA          NA
2000-01-14  0.062893082 NA          NA
2000-01-17  0.052910053 NA          NA
2000-01-18  0.031413613 NA          NA
2000-01-19  0.052910053 NA          NA
2000-01-20  0.051282051 NA          NA
2000-01-21  0.051282051 0.014184397 NA
2000-01-24  0.051282051 0.014184397 NA
2000-01-25  0.051282051 0.014184397 NA
2000-01-26  0.051282051 0.014184397 NA
2000-01-27  0.051282051 0.019914651 NA
2000-01-28  0.031088083 0.028571429 NA
2000-01-31  0.031088083 0.028571429 NA
```

The output I want

```
Monthly<- df
Month          A        B   C
Jan-2000    0.053656996 NA  NA
```

I would really apprecaite your help. And any ideas I want round off these values to 4 decimal places for instance 0.062893082   to 0.0628.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), then we use `format` to extract the month-year (after converting to `Date` class).  This can be used as a grouping variable.  We loop through the columns (`lapply(.SD,...`) and `if` the `length` of non-NA elements are greater than or equal to 15 get the `mean` or `else` return as NA.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,lapply(.SD, function(x) if(length(na.omit(x)) >=15)
       mean(x, na.rm=TRUE) else NA_real_) ,
             by = .(Month= format(as.IDate(Date), '%b-%Y'))]
#      Month        A  B  C
#1: Jan-2000 0.053657 NA NA
```

---

A similar approach using `dplyr` would be

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(Month = format(as.Date(Date), '%b-%Y')) %>%
    summarise_each(funs( if(length(na.omit(.))>=15) 
                       mean(., na.rm=TRUE) else NA_real_), A:C)
#    Month        A     B     C
#     (chr)    (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
#1 Jan-2000 0.053657    NA    NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("2000-01-04", "2000-01-05", "2000-01-06", 
"2000-01-07", "2000-01-10", "2000-01-11", "2000-01-12", "2000-01-13", 
"2000-01-14", "2000-01-17", "2000-01-18", "2000-01-19", "2000-01-20", 
"2000-01-21", "2000-01-24", "2000-01-25", "2000-01-26", "2000-01-27", 
"2000-01-28", "2000-01-31"), A = c(0.062893082, 0.062893082, 
0.062893082, 0.062893082, 0.062893082, 0.062893082, 0.062893082, 
0.062893082, 0.062893082, 0.052910053, 0.031413613, 0.052910053, 
0.051282051, 0.051282051, 0.051282051, 0.051282051, 0.051282051, 
0.051282051, 0.031088083, 0.031088083), B = c(0.030769231, 0.015503876, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.014184397, 0.014184397, 
0.014184397, 0.014184397, 0.019914651, 0.028571429, 0.028571429
), C = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Date", "A", "B", "C"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Comment: I ran this code `Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(DF3), , lapply(.SD, function(x) if (length(na.omit(x)) >=  : 
  Column 10 of result for group 2 is type 'double' but expecting type 'logical'. Column types must be consistent for each group.`

Comment: @Aquarius Can you try `else NA_real_`

Comment: Thank you!The code ran I got the desired output but I want to manually go through my result and then I will accept your answer, I hope you understand. I have a question If I want to omit the condition of 15 days as well the resultant date format to be 01-2000 rather than Jan-2000. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Aquarius It's okay.  In that case, just change the `format` statement i.e. `format(as.Date(Date), '%m-%Y'))`

Comment: it has been a while but could you please suggest me if how to calculate yearly averages from these monthly averages. This time there is no condition (if ). I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Aquarius In that case, after you got the result, say `res`, then `res %>% group_by(Year= sub('\\D+', '', Month)) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean))`

Comment: one more thing the Month column created has date format as Jan-00 but I don't know how it is now a factor(class).

Comment: @Aquarius It is not a `Date` class.  The `sub` step will convert the `factor` to `character`

Comment: I recieve error `Error: could not find function "%>%"`

Comment: @Aquarius You have to load `dplyr` or `magrittr` i.e. `library(dplyr)`

Comment: It works! Just one last thing how could I change Year column which has year as 00 to 2000.

Comment: @Aquarius You can use `%>%mutate(Year = ifelse(Year=="00", 2000, Year))`

Comment: Yearly is my new df  which contains the yearly averages,so, ran the code after running the library(dplyr) as `Yearly %>%mutate(Year = ifelse(Year=="00", 2000, Year))` but nothing changes in the output

Comment: @Aquarius Have you assigned it? i.e. `Yearly <- Yearly %>% ungroup %>% mutate...`

Comment: Sorry about that but now only year 2000 changes not the rest. Rest are still 01 02. Should I give range`00:14`

Comment: @Aquarius I thought you want to change only `00`.  If you need to append `20` then use `paste` i.e. `%>% mutate(Year= paste('20', Year))`

Comment: But this way the year appears like 20 00 , 20 01 and so. The format of first is nice, should I loop is some how

Comment: @Aquarius You can use `paste0` or `paste('20', Year, sep="")`

Comment: I ran `YearTO <-YearlyTO  %>% mutate(Year= paste('20', Year, sep="")` but still the same 20 00 format.

Comment: @Aquarius  I get `paste(20, '00', sep="")
#[1] "2000"`  Do you have leading space in "Year"? IN that case `library(stringr); YearlyTO %>% mutate(Year=paste('20', str_trim(Year), sep="")`

Comment: I don't why I'm still getting 20 00. But thanks alot for your kind help and really being so patient with me.

Comment: one more thing for yearly calculated averages, how can I add to code to omit NA. Because if for a column there are NAs the yearly average is also NA. I highly appreciate your help

Comment: @Aquarius  Have you tried the `na.rm=TRUE` as showed in the post

Comment: Yes `YTO <-Residuals %>% group_by(Year= sub('\\D+', '', Month)) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm=TRUE)))` but in the resultant output I have NaN I want NAs

Comment: @Aquarius I think the `NaN` results when all the elements in a particular group is `NA`.  In that case, you may use `na.omit` to remove the rows

Comment: Hi! it has been a while again but I ran this code to conduct monthly averages without any condition as `df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(Month = format(as.Date(Date), '%b-%Y')) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm=TRUE)))`  but in the out I get alphabettically arranged rows by month for example Apr 2000 Apr 2001.. and then Feb 2000 and Feb 2001 rather then Jan 2000 Feb 2000. Could you please tell me by mistake here

Comment: @Aquarius You could convert the column to a factor with levels specified, then it will arrange iin the order you wanted it to be.

Comment: I have converted it to factor by `df$Month <- as.factor(df$Month)` but still no luck how to reorder it. I changed the date formate to 01-2000 i.e `%m-%Y`

Comment: 15 years from 2000 to 2014

Comment: @Aquarius Try `lvls <- do.call(paste, c(expand.grid(month.abb, 2000:2014), list(sep='-')));df1 %>%  group_by(Month = factor(format(as.Date(Date), '%b-%Y'), levels=lvls))`

Comment: It creates a vector which has arranged from Jan 2000 Feb 2000 so on

Comment: @Aquarius It does create that.  You must have noticed that I converted the 'Month' column in 'group_by' to factor with levels= lvls.  and after that try with `summarise_each(...`

Comment: @Aquarius The full command is `lvls <- do.call(paste, c(expand.grid(month.abb, 2000:2014), list(sep='-')));df1 %>% group_by(Month = factor(format(as.Date(Date), '%b-%Y'), levels=lvls)) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm=TRUE)))`

Comment: Nope nothing. The vector is being created again. I stuck on this for long now :(

Comment: @Aquarius I tried this on some example and it is working.

Comment: akrun should I use df1 the one that has daily observations?

Comment: @Aquarius My code was based on the example data in my post.

Comment: Alright akrun thanks alot. I will try to work around it, you are indeed very helpful.